# Download one thing at time or the entire db?

Tags: database, performance

I am actually developing some sort of question-answers example app in javascript, which eventually will be transformed in a smartphone app.
The questions and the answer are on a db.

My question is this one: Is it better that everytime I want a question on the screen the app makes an ajax connection to the server and retrieve the complete question-answer json object... Or to retrieve all the questions and answers just the first time and move the logic inside the client?..

I'd like to know if there were some guidelines to follow or some rules which make the decisions on..

I.B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the client will likely need all data then you should probably provide it all in one go. The exception to that rule is if the data is too big and would exhaust some resource like network, CPU or memory if taken all at once. In that case small chunks are appropriate.

Comment: Ok let's say the this question-answer app can be finished before using all the questions, so one can exit the app just after 2 or 3 questions.. Is it still a good idea on providing all in one go?.. I really ask these questions because I don't have a clue about designing these things.. The data should't be too big, maybe 100 questions and 100 answers... Is there any advantage in using small chuncks from the application managing point of view? I was wondering if using small chuncks can be used to trace the use of the application in the server side or to include some ads.. just to know :)

Comment: It is a hard choice to make. As there is no clear answer all I can say is pro's and con's of each approach. If you ask for more data after each question your app might have a little more user-visible latency which is a disadvantage. If you want to track stuff you can still load all question data at one and send an "invisible" background AJAX to the server that contains just the tracking information. That would be the best of both worlds.